# Magento 2: Errors shown despite being in production mode

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I have a Magento 2.3.0 installation and it has been deployed with deploy mode 'production'. Running `bin/magento deploy:mode:show` shows:
`Current application mode: production. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.)`.

But still errors seem not to be hidden from visitors. As an example, when I enable the maintenance mode, they get to see this error when visiting the frontend:

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled.

Since the site is in production mode, I would not expect this (Exception should not be shown to visitors). How to fix this?

Comment: If you use apache, check the root htaccess file. There is an override as an environment variable for magentos mode.

Comment: I checked it, but it's not set there.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please execute this command `php bin/magento maintenance:status` to check if maintenance mode is still enabled. If so disable maintenance mode.

Comment: Maintenance mode being on is not the problem. I enabled it on purpose to test if an error would be shown. In production mode, the error should not shown like this, still it does.